# MySQL: find most recent value for list of subdocuments

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a collection `content` that has four columns; `id`, `timestamp`, `locationID`, and `authorID`.  Here is an example of my data; in production, this is tens of millions of rows in length.

```
id    timestamp              locationID   authorID
1     2012-03-01 11:52:00    1            1
2     2012-03-16 19:56:00    1            2
3     2012-04-02 11:26:00    2            1
4     2012-04-22 11:52:00    2            3
5     2012-05-19 09:48:00    2            2
6     2012-05-30 07:12:00    2            1
7     2012-06-04 19:17:00    1            2
```

I'd like to collect the list of `authorIDs` whose most recent `content` (ordered by `timestamp`) matched a specific `locationID`.

The correct values for a query of `locationID = 2` would be: `[ 1, 3 ]`, as `authorID` 1 and 3 were most recently 'seen' at `locationID = 2`, while `authorID` 2's most recent content was at `locationID` 1.

I can certainly execute one query per `authorID`, but on production the `authorID` array has a length >100,000.  This seems terribly inefficient (especially when each 'subquery' would be hitting this multi-million row `content` collection), and I'm looking for a better way to emerge this data from my dataset, ideally fast enough to be executed on a page render.

Comment: i'm confused. why `1,3` for location 2? isn't it `1,2` as the recent timestamps were `2012-05-19 09:48:00` and `2012-05-30 07:12:00`?

Comment: can you show the exact desired output shown in rows
?

Comment: @JW. `authorID` 2 posted in `locationID` 1, so they should no longer be displayed when I want to find "all authors whose latest post was at location 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  This is from SQL Server, but I think it should work in mySQL as well.

```
DECLARE @locationId INT
SET @locationId = 2;

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT AuthorId, Max(TimeStamp) as MaxTimeStamp
    FROM Content C
    WHERE LocationId = @locationId
    GROUP BY AuthorId) AS CBL
    LEFT JOIN Content AS C ON CBL.AuthorId = C.AuthorId
        AND C.TimeStamp > CBL.MaxTimeStamp
WHERE C.AuthorId IS NULL
```

For locationId = 2, it returns 1 and 3; and for locationId = 1, it returns 2

Per JW (thanks!), the correct mySql approach:

```
SET @locationId := 2;

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT AuthorId, Max(TimeStamp) as MaxTimeStamp
    FROM Content C
    WHERE LocationId = @locationId
    GROUP BY AuthorId) AS CBL
    LEFT JOIN Content AS C ON CBL.AuthorId = C.AuthorId
        AND C.TimeStamp > CBL.MaxTimeStamp
WHERE C.AuthorId IS NULL
```

Comment: This appears to work, but it's slow (7.76s for production).  I'll tackle this with `FORCE INDEX`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try derieved subquery

```
SELECT
    *
FROM content  as c
INNER JOIN(
            SELECT 
                MAX(id) as ID
            FROM content 
            WHERE locationID = 2
            GROUP BY authorID
) as t on t.ID = c.id
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9053/14)

Comment: What if `ID` is not strictly sequential?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me.  Given locationId = 2 above, it's returning author ids 1, 2, and 3

Comment: and this is what desired.i think OP has forgot to mention authorId 1